# extracting exact path from text in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

suppose I have a data.frame where each line is a text like the following:

```
text<-"Odysea Greek Extra Virgin 1.38 (0.43/100 ml) Subscribe & Save Get"
```

and I want to extract portions of text (using R) that looks like this:
"`0.43/100 ml`", considering that from a line to another, there could be more or less different spaces and characters, eg. "`00.451  /100 gr`", etc.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
extraction<-as.data.frame(gsub(pattern=[^"\\([:space:]*[:print:]*[:space:]*/[:space:]*[:print:]*\\)]", "", text))
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
gsub('.*?\\(([^)]*)\\).*', '\\1', text)
#[1] "0.43/100 ml"
```

Demo

```
.*?\\(([^)]*)\\).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Gm0RSKCkqCPxzaXK)

Comment: It works, great! But I could not understand how, even if you sent me the Debuggex. Is there a way to look out does it work on my text string? Thanks!

Comment: @UmbertoMedicamento I will update with some explanations.  I have to go now.

Comment: I (mostly) found out how to do it working with "add new unit test" in debuggex.com, thanks!

Comment: @UmbertoMedicamento  Glad to know you found it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/1

For r it may be

```
(?<=\\()[^)]*(?=\\))
```

`Lookbehind` will make sure you have `(` and lookahead will make sure yo have `)` ahead of what evet you capture.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But it deletes what I'm interested in, meanwhile I want to keep it. The demo is wonderful, really useful to learn about Regex. But how to adjust a regex for R once detected with the demo?

Comment: @UmbertoMedicamento grab the match instead of using gsub.

Answer (score 1):

Could also try the `qdapRegex` package and it `rm_` methods

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_round(text, extract = TRUE)[[1]]
## [1] "0.43/100 ml"
```

Comment: I think `qdap` also has similar ones like `bracketXtract`

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I'll try the bracketXtract too. But what if I have more brackets in the same line and, say, I want to select only the 1st, or the 3rd, etc.?

Comment: `rm_round(text, extract = TRUE)` will give you list of all the values within brackets, you can select the ones you want afterwards, for example `unlist(rm_round(text, extract = TRUE))[c(1,3)]` should work in order to exctract the first and the third element.